# How to add constraints to columns with specific conditions while creating table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my SQL for creating table Athlete:

```
CREATE TABLE Athlete 
(
 athelete_id NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
 athlete_lname VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
 athlete_fname VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
 athlete_dob DATE NOT NULL,
 athlete_email VARCHAR2(50) UNIQUE,
 athlete_gender VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL
);
```

For athlete_gender column, How to add a constraint with either M or F only ?

Next is my SQL to create Olympic_Game table:

```
CREATE TABLE Olympic_Game (
    og_id                NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    og_type_id           NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    og_year              NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    og_website           VARCHAR2(150),
    og_cancel            VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
    country_country_id   NUMBER(3) NOT NULL
);
```

How to add UNIQUE constraints for combination of og_year column and og_type_id column?

Next is my SQL to create Event table:

```
CREATE TABLE Event (
    event_id             NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    sport_sport_id       NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    olympic_game_og_id   NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    event_title          VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    event_team           VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
    no_per_team          NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    event_gender         VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL
);
```

For event_team column, how to add a constraint with either Y or N; default is N ?

For no_per_team column, how to add a constraint: if event_team is N then no_per_team = 1 otherwise no_per_team > 1; default is 1    ?

Comment: First of all this is not a pl/sql code. You can check Oracle documentation to add constraints, will get very similar examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Athlete 
(
 athelete_id NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
 athlete_lname VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
 athlete_fname VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
 athlete_dob DATE NOT NULL,
 athlete_email VARCHAR2(50) UNIQUE,
 athlete_gender VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT chk$athlete$gender CHECK ( athlete_gender IN ('M','F'))
);

CREATE TABLE Olympic_Game (
    og_id                NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    og_type_id           NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    og_year              NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    og_website           VARCHAR2(150),
    og_cancel            VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
    country_country_id   NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT un$og$year$type UNIQUE (og_year,og_type_id )
);

CREATE TABLE Event (
    event_id             NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    sport_sport_id       NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    olympic_game_og_id   NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    event_title          VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    event_team           VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL,
    no_per_team          NUMBER(2) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    event_gender         VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT chk$event$team CHECK ( event_team IN ('Y','N')),
    CONSTRAINT chk$event$no_team CHECK ((event_team='N' AND no_per_team=1) OR (event_team='Y' AND no_per_team>1))
);
```

Comment: LauDec ... I tested out your logic ... It has worked ... Really appreciate it.

Comment: LauDec .. I just have one last thing to clarify .. How about if I type this logic: CONSTRAINT chk$event$no_team CHECK (( IF event_team='N' THEN no_per_team=1) OR ( IF event_team='Y' THEN no_per_team>1)) ... Will this logic work ?

Comment: nope. IF statement is PL/SQL not SQL so it won't work. A CASE statement in the other hand is possible : CONSTRAINT chk$event$no_team CHECK ( CASE WHEN a='N' and b =1 THEN 1 WHEN a='Y' AND b>1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1 ).